# this.props.children returns null in react-router

Tags: react-router, reactjs

I am new to react-router.I was following this tutorial form https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/

This is the code i have written:-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, Link , IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

class Home extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.children);
    return(
       <div>
         <h2>Im home</h2>
         {this.props.children}
       </div>
      )
  }
}


class MainLayout extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }
  render(){
    return(
         <div className="app">
           <header className="primary-header">fdgfdgf</header>
           <aside className="primary-aside">
              <ul>
                <li><Link to="/users">Users</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/widgets">Widgets</Link></li>
              </ul>
           </aside>
           <main>
              {this.props.childern}
           </main>
         </div>
      )
  }
}

class SearchLayout extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }
  render(){
    return(
        <div className="search">
           <header className="search-header"></header>
           <div className="results">
              {this.props.childen}
           </div>
           <div class="search-footer pagination"></div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

class UserList extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }
  redner(){
    return(
          <ul className="user-list">
            <li>Dan</li>
            <li>Ryan</li>
            <li>Michael</li>
          </ul>       
      )
  }
}




ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
      <Route component={MainLayout}>
        <Route component={SearchLayout}>
          <Route path="/users" component={UserList} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

As far as i am concerned, the way i have set up routers i am expecting to see UserList component inside of SearchLayout Component,SearchLayout Component inside of MainLayout Component and the whole thing inside of Home Component when i visit the root of my page,which is localhost:8000 in my case.
But all i am seeing is the h2 tag inside of Home Component and console.log(this.props.children) logs null.

Comment: What version of React-Router are you using, and what version is the tutorial written for?

Comment: i am using react version 3.0.2. react version 4 had some issues importing browserHistory and hashHistory  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4711#issuecomment-286053526

Comment: Also you notice you are using redner() and not actually rendering the component

Comment: @ashish For what it's worth, the tutorial was posted on March 14, 2016. React-Router 3.0.0 [was released](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v3.0.0) October 24, 2016.

Comment: UserList `render` is misspelled

Comment: thanks for pointing out that render spelling typo, correcting the spelling didn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about now? Not sure about your structure though?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, Link , IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

const Home = (props)=>{
        console.log(props)
       return (<div>
         <h2>Im home</h2>
         {props.children}
       </div>)}


const MainLayout = (props)=>
         <div className="app">
           <header className="primary-header">fdgfdgf</header>
           <aside className="primary-aside">
              <ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/users">Users</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/widgets">Widgets</Link></li>
              </ul>
           </aside>
           <main>
              {props.children}
           </main>
         </div>


const SearchLayout = (props) =>
        <div className="search">
           <header className="search-header"></header>
           <div className="results">
              {props.children}
           </div>
           <div className="search-footer pagination"></div>
        </div>


const UserList = ()=>
          <ul className="user-list">
            <li>Dan</li>
            <li>Ryan</li>
            <li>Michael</li>
          </ul>       

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
        <Route component={SearchLayout}>
        <Route path={'/users'} component={UserList} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: thanks, worked fine,but when i click on users i am not getting UserList component. Sorry,if it's a silly question, i am quite new to react-routers!

Comment: Notice you've spelled {this.props.childern} instead of this.props.children inside the main tags

Comment: Thanks again for pointing out the typo, didn't solved the issue mentioned yet!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you're visiting localhost:8000 instead of localhost:8000/users

At localhost:8000, it matches the "/" path with only has the Home component. To see the UsersList inside of SearchLayout, inside of MainLayout, inside of Home, you need to go to /users. If you want the above to load at "/" you should add an IndexRoute above UserList:

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
      <Route component={MainLayout}>
        <Route component={SearchLayout}>
          <IndexRoute component={MyIndexComponent} />
          <Route path="/users" component={UserList} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```